# Find Razor used inside script tags

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, razor, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2010/2012, how can I find all the script tags that might contain javascript mixed up with Razor?

This should be matches:

```
<script>
    var hola = '@serverVariable';
    alert(hola);
</script>

<script>
    var somenumber = @Int32.MaxValue;
    alert(somenumber );
</script>

<script>        
    @if(someFlag)
    {           
       @:alert('hello');
    }else{
       @:alert('bye');
    }
</script>
```

This shouldn't be matches:

```
<script>
    @* A valid comment *@
    alert(hola);
</script>

<script>
    alert('hola  @@');
</script>

<script>
    alert('hola');
</script>
```

I'm trying this as the Regexp but VisualStudio takes hours to find all references, it is recursive and I don't know how to break the recursion.

```
<script{1}([\s\r\n]|.)*?[^*@]@[^*@]([\s\r\n]|.)*?</script{1}
```

Comment: If someone wonders why, let's say I arrived "late" to the party and I have to clean up the trash. Razor mixed with JavaScript is the worst idea ever!

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Comment: No, this gives no matches. But thanks

Comment: I tried my regex in VS 2010 Pro with Quick Find (Select Use Regular Expressions) and it worked perfectly on your example data.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work. It assumes no `<` between the script tags.

```
\<script\>([^<]|\n)*[^*@]\@[^*@]([^<]|\n)*\</script\>
```

`@` seems to need to be escaped in VS regular expressions - it *sometimes* matches the space character.
The `<` and `>` need to be escaped as otherwise they indicate the start/end of a word.

I recommend you use a text editor with a better regular expression engine, for example Notepad++, or try an add-in: [NET Regular Expressions Find and Replace Add-In for Visual Studio 2008](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26929/NET-Regular-Expressions-Find-and-Replace-Add-In-f).